# How i can use functions that is not extended

Tags: java, android

I got an Activity that is already extending from SherlockActivity
Now i want to use a DialogFragment with support library

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
HelpDialogFragment testDialog = new HelpDialogFragment();
testDialog.setRetainInstance(true);
testDialog.show(fm, "fragment_name");
```

But getSupportFragmentManager(); cannot be used if i do not extend from FragmentActivity which i can't due to the SherlockActivity.
Anyone that can give me some directions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend your activity from SherlockFragmentActivity, your Fragments from SherlockFragment and your DialogFragments from SherlockDialogFragment